# Can anybody tell me how to payout to User account using RazorPay Flutter either through flutter library or post request

Tags: flutter, razorpay, payout, flutter-razorpay

The Payment Integration it's my first time, I have successfully integrate RazerPay for my Flutter project using the standard razorpay_flutter library from pub.dev, But there is only checkout function in there. Checkout is completely working, but how to transfer (received) funds to users account! There is no document on library for payout or transfers, I think it can be done with post API'S but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Razorpay has another banking product called razorpayx and it has its own api's through which payments can be done.

Your first need to create and contact, then fund account and then initiate the payout request. There are api's for each one of these.

There is also composite api which does the above 3 steps in one api request.

refer to postman [collection](https://www.postman.com/razorpaydev/workspace/razorpay-public-workspace/folder/12492020-fcd32a4a-0c53-41a7-a879-d771de7e2804)

So now in whichever language or framework you are using, you will need to hit  the above api